# Complex number, logarithm and exponential

Tags: complex-numbers

Find

i)$Log(-ei)$

ii)$Log(1-i)$

I'm not too sure about how to solve this, what I did is

Take $z=-ei$ so $Log(z)=\log r + i\theta, \space r>0, \space -\pi<\theta\leq\pi$
$$r=\sqrt{0+e^2}=e\rightarrow Log(z)=1+i\theta, r>0,-\pi<\theta\leq\pi$$
To find $\theta$ $$x=r\cos\theta \rightarrow0=e\cos\theta $$
$$y=r\sin\theta\rightarrow -e=e\sin\theta$$

So $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, but that is not within the limit of $\theta$, can anyone help me step by step?

If anyone can give me even a hint in item ii) thank also

Comment: The angle is cyclic with $2 \pi$ cycle; just take $-0.5 \pi$

Comment: You can solve the second one in the same way.

Comment: @Mike Oh thanks man, had not paid attention to it.

Comment: BTW, this is NOT complex-analysis, so I guess you should remove this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is:

$\ln(-ei)=\ln(e)+ln(-i)=1+\ln(i^{-1})=1-\ln(i)=1-\ln(e^{-i\pi/2})=1+i\pi/2$.

The second is $\ln\sqrt 2.e^{i.\pi/4}=\ln\sqrt2+\ln e^{i\pi/4}=\dfrac{\ln2}{2}+\dfrac{i\pi}{4}=\dfrac{\ln2+2\pi i}{4}$.

Comment: also $\ln(-i)=\ln(e^{i\pi/2})$...